# Not able to import Salesforce Campaign to Exact Target campaign

Tags: marketing-cloud

Currently it is not possible to import salesforce Campaigns into ExactTarget campaigns using out of box functionality.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've implemented the [Marketing Cloud Connect](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/) connector, then it *is* possible.

If you don't want to use the Connector then you'll need to extract the SF report to a file, place it on an SFMC SFTP share and then use an [Import Activity](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/) to import the data into a SFMC Data Extension.  This process can be automated using [Automation Studio](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/), if needed.

Comment: I am using Marketing cloud connector and I am talking about connecting SF Campaign and ET Campaign (Which is available in top section).What You have told that will simply create data extension,but ET campaings and SF campaigns will not be connected.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that I think ET campaigns and SF Campaigns is different or means different things.